# Following error in Netbeans7 when trying to create a new project

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans7.0

I am getting the below error in the "Select Project Location" screen when trying to create a New Project from NetBeans7

Dialog seems to be slow, probably because of JDK bug. Please try to upgrade JDK, remove zip files from Desktop folder or run ssytem with **-J-Dnb.FileChooser.useShellFolder=false** property

What does this mean? what action should I do ?

I do have NEtbeans 6.7/6.8 also installed in my system. Will that matters ?
Also,
Configured Netbeans7's JDK is using the one Netbeans7 installer gets from glassfish server  and my sytem JAVA-HOME is still pointing to my old jdk1.5.

Answer (score 5):

1. Java needs lot of time to display a directory which has big ZIP files as it tried to load all the metadata from the ZIP file also for inspection.  When NetBeans IDE shows a file chooser dialog box, it may have detected such a case and is warning you not to use a directory which has big ZIP files in it.  If you have some biz ZIP files in the concerned directory you may try removing them or keeping your project in some sub directory.
2. Your Desktop folder may be having some big ZIP files and to load the desktop contents in the file chooser dialog Java will take lot of time, hence it is recommended to move all the ZIP files in the desktop to some sub-folders on desktop to avoid this warning.
3. The version of Java or versions of NetBeans IDE installed on your machine has nothing to do with your issue.  This warning is shown to make the user aware why lot of time is taken to display the file chooser dialog box (When there are big ZIP files in Desktop or C: or D: locations of your disk)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I know why NetBeans asks me to *remove zip files from my desktop to avoid a JDK bug* ^^

Comment: Tushar
1. This is a JDK BUG. There is no justification for trying to pass it off as a feature.
2. In MPLABX I get this long delay while navigating in all dialogue windows when trying to change directories. It doesn't matter whether there is a zip file or not.
3. Its been over 10 years so maybe there are other factors that need to be considered.